# My custom flutter bottomappbar elevate when I chose the item

Tags: flutter

I made my own custom bottom appbar.
There's 5 items and each of it has image icon and text.
When I tap the item, the item of the bottom appbar is elevating for 2dp.

```
   child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.transparent, // BottomAppBar의 배경색을 투명하게 설정
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Gaps.v23,
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Gaps.v8,
                  GnbTap(
                    text: '교외 지원', //this is korean
                    isSelected: _selectedIndex == 0,
                    onTap: () => _onTap(0),
                    selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                    selecetedImage: AppImages.outSchool_active,
                    unselecetedImage: AppImages.outSchool_inactive,
                  ),
                  GnbTap(
                    text: '교내 지원',//this is korean
                    isSelected: _selectedIndex == 1,
                    onTap: () => _onTap(1),
                    selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                    selecetedImage: AppImages.school_active,
                    unselecetedImage: AppImages.school_inactive,
                  ),
```

*when I tap the first item ->

[image]

*when I tap the seconf item ->

[image]

I searched and saw what can I use from the bottomappbar widget..but I cannot find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the code of your `BottomAppBar` component so it's difficult to find the root of the cause, but in case you're using Scaffold's `BottomNavigationBar` widget, you will just need to do something like this.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  selectedFontSize: 14.5,
  unselectedFontSize: 14.5,
  selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(
    size: 20
  ),
  unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(
    size: 20
  ),
  items: const [],
  currentIndex: 0,
  onTap: ((index) {})
)
```

By making the `selectedFontSize` equal to the `unselectedFontSize` it will assure that the font size of the text will never change regardless of whether they're selected or not. It's also the same way with the icon size of `selectedIconTheme` and the `unselectedIconTheme`.